# Updating record in an Ember Data record array

Tags: ember.js

I need to update some of the data in my model, which happens to be a DS.RecordArray in this case, from the controller. My intention is to avoid having to do another API call to get the updated array after a save(). I am not sure what the best way to access specific elements of the RecordArray and modify them is.

I'm also not sure if there's a better way to avoid the circular reference error I was receiving before I converted the model to a regular Ember array. Here is the code:

```
        var subtypes = Ember.A();
            this.get('model').forEach(function(subtype){
            //converting the RecordArray to a regular array to 
            //avoid circular reference error
            subtypes.pushObject(subtype);
        });

        let task = this.store.createRecord('savetask', {
            id: 'savesubtypes',
            docketType: this.get('docket'),
            category: this.get('category'),
            docSubtypes: subtypes
        });
            task.save().then((result) => {
            //API returns task with modifications to
            //docSubtypes

            result.get('docSubtypes').forEach(function(subtype) {
                //need to modify the RecordArray with the changed values from 
                //the API. How to match these records with the ones on the model?
            }, this);
```

Please let me know if anything is unclear

Comment: Why do you even need the property DS.RecordArray? I really miss the point of doing that since you could just make another model and set the relationship of type `hasMany`, have you considered this?

Comment: I've considered it, but wasn't sure that would make this situation any more easier. If  I understand correctly, you're suggesting I make something like a 'subtypeslist' model that hasMany on 'subtype'? If I were to do this, I'm still not sure how to modify that new model based upon the 'result' of the task.save

Answer (score 0):

I give you a full example to reveal power of Ember data.

Let's assume you have

```
/model/contact.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  notes: DS.hasMany(),
  date: DS.attr(),
  firstName: DS.attr(),
  lastName: DS.attr(),

});
```

and your note model should be

```
/model/note.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  contact: DS.belongsTo(),
  reference: DS.attr(),
  date: DS.attr(),
  content: DS.attr()
});
```

Now suppose you want to save a new note for this contact so it's very easy rather than make it complicated: I assume you want to do that when an action trigger so I define a function like newNote

```
/rounte for example you want to save this note in rounte/note.js / template/note.hbs
newNote: function(noteContent) {
      var newNoteData = {
        content: noteContent, // Pass the notecontent to the function
        contact: this.currentModel.get('contact'), //get your contact 

      };
      this.store.createRecord('note', newNoteData).save().then(() => {
          //do your notification or consolo.log('DONE');
      }, function() {
          // catch your error if any, alert('not saved !') 
      });
    }
```

you template would be like

```
 <form class="form" {{action "newNote" noteContent on="submit" }}>
      {{textarea value=noteContent placeholder="Quick Note" class="form-control custom-control" rows="2"}}
         <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>
```

that's it. you basically don't need to anything else and the rest will be handled by Ember itself. If you do this way you will find out that the note list on your pages also will be updated immediately and a request will be sent to your API as well.

I hope this simple code can give you more insight and you can refine your code based on this and get the best result.

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful. Although, I think some of the functionality I need is not included. In the context of your example, my API is making changes to the 'note' record in its save() callback. I need to then receive those changes in somehing like 
      this.store.createRecord('note', newNoteData).save().then((result) => {
          //update the corresponding contact and note model based on changes in API
      }

Comment: of course, you must change the context to whatever you want this is just an example of how you can implement. Try if you need more help, let me know and please provide more details thanks.

Comment: I am using store.query('docSubtype', { //params}) (store.query returns a DS.RecordArray) to populate the model for this route. Next, the user makes changes on the UI which alter the models, followed by clicking a submit button which triggers the save() listed above. As a result of the save, the backend receives the task object, modfiies the 'docSubtypes' object on the task, and send it back. I need to grab that 'docSubtypes' object from the result and re-populate the RecordArray of models in Ember with it. Not sure how to complete this re-population step. Does that make sense?

Comment: if I understand correctly , you don't need to repopulate again, it will be done for you automatically, you when you have an action for submit you just declare an action with  this.store.createRecord('note', newdata).save().then(() => {
          you can use this.set('whatever','to whatever); 
      } then means when you communicate with your backup the result will be grabbed again and your UI  will be updated automatically. Means the repopulation actually will be done in Model then in your Route.